# React Hook Form error messages not updating correctly with dynamic fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using React Hook Form with dynamic fields for teams. While the validation works and displays errors correctly upon submit, the error messages don't disappear when I correct the input. Here's the relevant code:

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(1, 'Please enter a name'),
  team: z.array(
    z.object({
      name: z.string().min(1, 'Please enter a name'),
      role: z.string().min(1, 'Please enter a role'),
    })
  ).max(10).optional(),
});

const formMethods = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      ...defaultValues,
    } as FormValues,
    validationResolver,
    validationContext: formSchema,
  });

const {
    fields: teamFields,
    append: appendTeamFields,
    remove: removeTeamFields,
  } = useFieldArray({ name: 'team', control: formMethods.control });
```

Temeplate

```
{teamFields.map((_, idx) => (
  <div key={idx}>
    <input
      name={`team[${idx}].name`}
      ref={formMethods.register(`team[${idx}].name`)}
    />
    <input
      name={`team[${idx}].role`}
      ref={formMethods.register(`team[${idx}].role`)}
    />
    {formMethods.errors?.team?.[idx]?.name && 
      <span>
        {formMethods.errors.team[idx].name.message}
      </span>
    }
    {formMethods.errors?.team?.[idx]?.role && 
      <span>
        {formMethods.errors.team[idx].role.message}
      </span>
    }
  </div>
))}
```

Im using `react-hook-form": "^5.7.2"`, If I submit with errors, they display correctly. After correcting the input, the error messages remain displayed until I submit again.

Answer (score 0):

What version of react-hook-form is this? I can't see that it returns errors directly in formMethods. They are inside formState.

It is explained in the documentation when the validation get triggered. https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode   . It is on submit. You can change it to onChange

Comment: It's react-hook-form": "^5.7.2", The issue is there is another filed in my form that isn't included in the example. but you can see that in the schema it's called "name".it's behaves differently. if that name field doesn't have a value on onSubmit it will display the error and if I apply more than one character on it will disappear. but in the dynamic fields, it does the same thing once I try to submit it with empty values except the error message doesn't go away when I enter values on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to write an ".", on registration of you team fields.

```
{teamFields.map((_, idx) => (
  <div key={idx}>
    <input
      name={`team.${idx}.name`}
      ref={formMethods.register(`team.${idx}.name`)}
    />
    <input
      name={`team.${idx}.role`}
      ref={formMethods.register(`team.${idx}.role`)}
    />
    {formMethods.errors?.team?.[idx]?.name && 
      <span>
        {formMethods.errors.team[idx].name.message}
      </span>
    }
    {formMethods.errors?.team?.[idx]?.role && 
      <span>
        {formMethods.errors.team[idx].role.message}
      </span>
    }
  </div>
))}
```

I think that you could omit the "name" parameter of the inputs fields since you are using the "register" function. I think it injects the name parameter by default.

Comment: All of my code works fine only thing that doesn't work is if the user tries to submit without any value it displays the error and then the user types in it should disappear. That part is not working. couldn't figure out why it works for static inputs and not works dynamic inputs.

Comment: The point is that maybe you are registering the fields with theyr name wrong. The final name string should be "team.index.name", and you are writing as "team.[index].name". That way the fields didn't even registered currently. So they aren't being listened.